# Error returning null from generic type object C#

Tags: c#, generic-handler

I am having issue returning null from generic type object in BSTree

> This Is the Error : A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.exe
>    Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued

and my code it

```
        public BTree()  //creates an empty tree
    {
        root.Name = default(T);
        root.Members = default(T);
    }
```

Thanks

I set root to be :

```
public BST()
    {
        root = null;
    }
```

Comment: what type is T..? is it a string ..? int..?

Comment: What is `root`?  Is it `null` at runtime?  If so, then trying to access `.Name` or `.Members` on it will result in a null reference exception.

Comment: I set root.Name and root.Members as default(T) as well but didnt work

Comment: @user2154803 if you know that `root` is `null` when you access its fields why are you asking?

Comment: can you show more code than that.. what does root look like..? also looks like you are not familiar with how to assign and or use default
here is an example `var someValue = default(string);` will `Initialize someValue = string.Empty` Show what `T` struct or Class, or Delegate etc.. looks like

Comment: Because I tried setting it to other types of null and still did not work, I tried root = default(T), and tried root.Name , root.Members = default(T) and they all did not work

Comment: `-1` for not showing all relevant code parts..

Comment: @user2154803 do you know that accessing members of a `null` object will give you `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: No I did not know that

Comment: @user2154803 you need to read some basic things about C# before touching generics.

Comment: @user2154803 Mate, when you post a question you need to take the time to carefully craft it to state what you're trying to achieve, what you've tried so far (and include ALL relevant code - if you're not sure what's relevant or not, err on the side of including too much and the community will trim it down for you later), and what errors/problems you're having (ideally, if you are able to narrow this down to a specific question rather than a broad "please just make this all work" type question...).  The more time you spend getting your question right, the more help you'll get.  Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `root` is currently `null` and you're getting an exception trying to set it's members.  Given that `BTree()` is a constructor and `root` a presumably instance field, you need to initialize it before use

```
public BTree() {
  root = new Artist<T>();
  root.Name = default(T);
  root.Members = default(T);
}
```

**EDIT**

Updated based on PasteBin code

Comment: I get a message the Type of namespace can not be found

Comment: @user2154803 because it is not code that you need to blindly copy-paste.

Comment: Believe me if I understood what my mistake is I would have searched C# documentation but I still fail to see what I am doing wrong

Comment: @user2154803 you are accessing fields of a null object.

Comment: I only know basics about generic , I had a working generic BSTree with only one data field and am now developing it to contain another extra field , so all I have been doing is extending the classes to hold the required extra data, but do not know how to null this object with the 2 fields. I am looking at all your solutions and trying to understand them

Comment: @user2154803 can you post the field definitions of `BTree`?

Comment: @user2154803 this has nothing to do with generics. You are accessing fields of a null object.

Comment: @user2154803 Why did you comment out the `new` call?

Comment: How come the exact code worked when I was only dealing with one data field ?

Comment: because it produced another error saying: the name Name does not exist in this context

Comment: @user2154803 so you didn't write that line and don't know what does it do?

Comment: I duplicated this and still have the original files and looking at them , again if you want I can paste them

Comment: @user2154803 paste what? and why?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/gsHTSVcC << this is the original file, that I wrote and worked with no problems and was only using one Data field in the Node

Comment: @user2154803 don't you see the differences? In the original file you are not accessing fields of `root` but instead assign `root` itself.

Comment: Thank you, Only know I understand my Mistake, I really appreciated the help you gave, Thanks again